# Android database, Can't check if item is in database already

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
public boolean proveri(String title1)
{
    Cursor mCursor=mDd.query(true,DATABASE_TABLE,new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_TITLE,KEY_BODY,KEY_TIP},KEY_TITLE+"="+title1,null, null,null,null,null);
    if (mCursor != null)
    {
        return false;

    }
    else{return true;}

}
```

// so Title is not define as primary key , +KEY_TITLE+" text not null l"

Comment: What's the problem? Does it fail with an exception or just give you wrong results? Anyway, your question is very poorly described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this `KEY_TITLE+"= '"+title1 +"'"`

Query value should be inside single quote.

Answer (score 0):

The `query` method returns an empty `Cursor` if no matches are found (rather than `null`), so you should add an additional check using `moveToFirst()`, which returns false if the `Cursor` is empty.

```
if (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) return false;
```